# React SSR - I have to Click browser Back button Twice to go back

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

We have a custom React SSR Project.

When on `localhost:3000/page` to go back to `localhost:3000` the back button has to be pressed twice.

Found out that it creates duplicate location history.

[image]

Comment: can you give us some snippets of your code?

Comment: The code itself is complicated. old codes, Just hope into this project.

Comment: @Hartha its SSR , everything's working perfectly. The Title changes but the Router don't change on single click

Comment: Just Found out That, it creates Duplicate path History

Comment: react router dom will not behave this way on its own even with SSR. The problem is coming from your code. Without any code it's unlikely we can guess what your issue might be and actually be right about it.